# ubuntu 16.04: autorun and automount - kernel level?

Tags: kernel, automount, autorun

I have to disable this two services. I've done this using the dconf editor.
Please, can you tell me at which O.S. level this happens ? That is: can you tell me if the disabling these two services, using the dconf editor, happens at kernel level ?